# Windows Phone 7 equivalent of Android's WebView

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, uiwebview, webview, browser

I'm starting to work with [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com), and see that it works using chromeless browser views and the url string of phones to reuse HTML/JS/CSS to build cross-platform applications.  I know in Android, this is a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html), and the iOS equivalent of this is a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  When I started to look for Windows Phone 7 and how to bring up the equivalent of a WebView, my Google skills failed me.

**What is the equivalent of an Android WebView in Windows Phone 7?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the equalivalent.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like the Windows Phone WebBrowser control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx